# How to preview automatically edited image after picking with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, image-processing, camera

I my app users can take and save photos, but before I save them on disk, I have to compress and downscale them. Is it possible to show automatically edited image in a standard preview screen right after user captured the image with UIImagePickerController? Or should I build my own camera with AVFoundation? If so, could anyone suggest some lightweight opensource camera for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to build your own solution with AVCaptureSession, which is not hard, since you more than likely will want to keep the original photo in a temp file, compress it, show it on a custom view with an image view in it and then ask the user if they want to save it or not.

Here's [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) but there are plenty tutorials on how to do this